# Use features with diffrent lengths of time to an ANN model

Tags: time-series, forecasting, forecast, economics

I'm trying to build a ANN model to predict oil prices and I have diffrent economic features, each one as a time serie.

I pretend to predict the monthly prices, but there are some features that are only avaliable in a annual period. Is it possible to use anyway these features to predict the monthly prices or only can use the monthly features?

Thank you an regards,

Gonzalma.

Comment: What kind of ANN architecture? Something like an MLP/fully connected does not have a concept of time, so this can be done without problem. If you use an RNN, resample your dataseries to have uniform intervals (monthly or smaller). For the things that change only yearly it just means many subsequent months will have the same value, and that is fine

Comment: Than you jonnor. Yes the architecture is a RNN and the doubt was if resample a annual variable in 12 months with the same value is apropiate, so perfect!